# how to use pthread or run jobs concurrently in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get huge amount of data (draw sample from huge population) using multiple MySQL queries in Laravel. which were time consuming.

how to do so in lumen v-7?

I really not much know about queue jobs, I want to run this concurrently, I dispatched 60 jobs with independent worker, and each job take approx 60 sec to be executed, Please see my example code, Thanks !

foreach( ... ) {
dispatch(new SampleJob( ...... )->onQueue('processChunk'.$chunk_id);
$commandvar=' php ' . base_path('artisan') . ' queue:work --queue=processChunk'.$chunk_id.' --once &';
$commandvar = str_replace('\', '/', $commandvar);
$command[]= $commandvar;
$chunk_id++;
$process = new Process( [ exec($commandvar)]);
$process->setTimeout(3600);
$processes[] = $process;

}

Comment: Look into queues: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas, but i already to use Laravel queue. it seems not running asynchronously, you can look into my code below,  can you please help me how to run jobs asynchronously?                                                                                                                   for each( ...   ){  dispatch(new Sample Job( ...... )->onQueue('processChunk'.$chunk_id  );  
   $commandvar=' php ' . base_path('artisan') . ' queue:work -- queue=processChunk'.$chunk_id.' --once &';                                                                    
   exec($commandvar) ​}

Comment: Please edit your question with the code. How are you running the worker? It appears that you are invoking this in PHP. The queue processing logic is intended to be invoked at the OS/shell level directly. For demo purposes, try just running multiple shells and having each run the worker. Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59563391/231316) which shows how to have Supervisord spawn multiple workers for you.

Comment: Also, we’re talking about concurrency here really, not async. The latter is a more abstract thing that is language or framework-specific, and also implies (regardless of whether or not the feature is used), the ability to communicate or pass data across each “processes”. If you _really_ want async PHP, you should check out [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/). Concurrency, however, is native to all modern computers. But, you can’t start a single process and (easily and safely) have itself spawn into multiple independent concurrent processes, you should start concurrent in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, i updated my question, Please check. Thanks